# Migrate local Sitecore to Azure Cloud

Tags: azure, cloud, express-migration-tool

I'm trying to migrate Sitecore on-prem to Azure Cloud.
In the first step of Sitecore Express Migration Tool 3.1, I need to put Source and Target locations.

In the field of the target source, how can I put the cloud's website physical path?

[image]

Do I need to set FTP mapping in Window Explore?

Comment: I couls be wrong, but I don't think the Migration Tool was meant to go from OnPrem to Azure. Maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Sitecore Express Migration Tool](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Express_Migration_Tool.aspx) helps you to migrate between different Sitecore versions. As soon as you have migrated to the version you need locally you deploy your solution to Azure.

If you would like to use Azure as an Infrastructure (IaaS) you can deploy your solution as you would do with any other Virtual Machine.

If you would like to use Azure Platform as a Service (PaaS) then you would need Sitecore version 8.2 update 1 (or later - v8.2 update 6 recommended) or version 9 and you can deploy your solution using the [Sitecore Azure Toolkit](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Azure_Toolkit/2x/Sitecore_Azure_Toolkit_200.aspx).

More information about how to use the Sitecore Azure Toolkit you can find here: https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/82/working_with_sitecore_azure/configuring_and_deploying_sitecore_azure/getting_started_with_sitecore_azure_toolkit